# What was Sri Rama's opinion on the caste system?

Tags: ramayana, rama, caste-system

Did Rama enforce castiesm or did he attempt to reform it or did he ignore it?

Comment: Caste system? There were no caste system during treta yuga. The society was divided into varnas.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto so then what was Rama's opinion on the Varna system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During Rama’s reign as king, the caste system was followed. Each case was engaged in happily performing their own assigned tasks. While giving a description of his reign, the Ramayana says:

> ब्राह्मणाः क्षत्रिया वैश्याः शूद्रा लोभविवर्जिताः।
> स्वकर्मसु प्रवर्तन्ते तुष्टाः स्वैरेव कर्मभिः॥१०४॥
>
> **Brahmins, Kshatriyas, Vaishyas and Shudras** devoid of greed, **engaged in their own occupations** and were satisfied with their own work. 
> -*Yuddha Kanda, Chapter 128, verse 104*

This shows us that he was a proponent of the caste system. It is also important to note that everyone was satisfied performing their own occupations. There was no forced casteism or anything of the nature.

---

<sup>Note: Just to clarify caste system does not mean the demonic context attributed to it by foreigners. It is the ancient Vedic system of Varna vyavastha, that has been referred to as caste system here.</sup>

Comment: I'm not sure if we are reading different translations of the Valmiki-Ramayana but I found your particular verse of the Yuddha Kanda in chapter 128 verse 105. So what translation or website are you using for the Valmiki-Ramayana translation?

Comment: I’m using sa.wiki source

Answer (score 1):

Rama showed by his actions that he was a strict believer in the caste system

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-ramayana-of-valmiki/d/doc424850.html

A Brahmin's son dies young and he blamed the king (Rama) for it

Chapter 73 - The Death of a Brahmin’s Son
parent: Book 7 - Uttara-kanda

> Having said farewell to Shatrughna, the fortunate Rama found satisfaction in ruling his kingdom in equity.
> Now some time after, an aged peasant, a brahmin, bearing his dead child in his arms came to the palace gate, weeping and crying out again and again:—
> “What sin did I commit in a previous existence?”

................

> With Rama as its protector, the death of children is certain. People perish under the unrighteous rule of an impious monarch. The evil conduct of a king brings about the premature death of his subjects. When, in the cities and country, crimes are committed and no supervision is exercised, then death is to be feared! Undoubtedly the king will be held to be at fault in city and country, hence the death of this child.”
> Such were the countless recriminations that the unfortunate father addressed to the king whilst he clasped his son to his breast.

..................

> Chapter 74 - Narada’s Discourse

> “O Prince, a man of the lowest caste may not give himself up to penance in the Dvapara Yuga; it is only in the Kali Yuga that the practice of asceticism is permitted to the Shudra caste. During the Dvapara Yuga it is a great crime for one of Shudra birth to perform such practices.
> “At this time, in thine empire, a rigid penance is being undertaken by a wretched Shudra, 0 Prince, and this is the cause of the death of that child.

.................

Chapter 76 - Shambuka is slain by Rama

> On this that Prince born of Raghu approached the one who had given himself up to rigorous practices and said:—
> “Blessed art you, O Ascetic, who art faithful to your vows! From what caste art you sprung, O You who hast grown old in mortification and who art established in heroism. I am interested in this matter, I, Rama, the son of Dasaratha. What purpose hast you in view? Is it heaven or some other object? What boon dost you seek by means of this hard penance? I wish to know what you desirest in performing these austerities, O Ascetic. May prosperity attend you! Art you a brahmin? Art you an invincible Kshatriya? Art you a Vaishya, one of the third caste or art you a Shudra? Answer me truthfully!”
> Then the ascetic, who was hanging head downwards, thus questioned by Rama, revealed his origin to that Prince born of Dasaratha, the foremost of kings, and the reason why he was. practising penance.

> Hearing the words of Rama of imperishable exploits, that ascetic, his head still hanging downwards, answered:—
> “O Rama, I was born of a Shudra alliance and I am performing this rigorous penance in order to acquire the status of a God in this body. I am not telling a lie, O Rama, I wish to attain the Celestial Region. Know that I am a Shudra and my name is Shambuka.”
> As he was yet speaking, Raghava, drawing his brilliant and stainless sword from its scabbard, cut off his head.

Rama summarily executed Shambuka while hanging upside-down in tapas without even telling him what crime he was being charged with.

Comment: @S K I do know of this story but alot of people say that Shambuka was killed because of him doing Tapas for the wrong reasons, is this reasoning true?

Comment: @Rajam - yes, a shudra was doing tapasya to obtain occult powers. This is no different from a layman entering a weapons depot to obtain grenades without clearance. *"without even telling him what crime he was being charged with."* - as if the person is a child who involuntarily entered the no trespassing zone. Military need not give any reason to execute that person on the spot.

Answer (score 1):

In *Adhyātma Rāmāyaṇa*, *Bhagavāna Rāmacandra* says to *Śabarī*

> पुंस्त्वे स्त्रीत्वे विशेषो वा जातिनामाश्रमादयः । न कारणं मद्भजने भक्तिरेव हि कारणम् ।। यज्ञदानतपोभिर्वा वेदाध्ययनकर्मभिः । नैव द्रष्टुमहं शक्यो मद्भक्तिविमुखैः सदा ।।
>
> Translation: Manhood, womanhood, **caste**, *āśrama* or any other such identities of name aren't the reasons for (being entitled to) my worship, devotion is the one & only cause. Activities like *yajña*, charity, austerities or study of the *Veda* can't grant my vision to that person who is devoid of devotion to me. [*Adhyātma Rāmāyaṇa*:2:10:20-21]

Comment: Where is the Adhyatma Ramayana found in?

Comment: @Rajam Adhyatma Ramayana is believed to be a part of the Brahmanda Purana, however modern-day publishers refuse to incorporate it in the printed version.

Comment: Oh so where did you get the translation of the text?

Comment: I do have a PDF version of Adhyātma Rāmāyaṇa with the Sanskrit original & its Hindi translation published by the Gita Press.

Comment: Do you have an English edition and if so can you please give me the PDF?